# How to stream an array of Objects to View in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

In .NET MVC, I want to GET a list of data from an API call and have the following code. I wonder whether it is possible to stream each data object to the View and show them as they become available, instead of waiting for the entire list to be finished and pass the completed list at the end.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{                                             
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    ResponseData[] listOfData = new ResponseData[1000000];

    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {   
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://someapiservice/{input[i]}");

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        listOfData[i] = data;
    }

    return View(listOfData);            
}
```

Comment: You are not really trying to return 1 million objects back to the view are you? But in any case, you can use a loop in the client to make multiple ajax calls to get one (or a few) objects at a time (passing the counter in each call)

Comment: Maybe not a million, but certainly thousands. Thanks.